# Updating a website only when variables change in flask

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, flask

Hello there stackoverflow community

I am doing a function in flask that updates a variable via post request and then processes this variable and shows it into a website, just like those sports livescore websites do.

The website its working as intended, but I am planning to have some few users, I think it would be much better than the website update once the variable var_g change, not every 2 seconds as now is implemented and would be incredible that all users get the update at the same time, hope you guys can help me

Any suggestion would be really helpful, I don’t have much experience and maybe i doing everything wrong.

Flask side

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request

# Global variable to keep everything updated
var_g = 0

app = Flask(__name__)

# Getting the post resquest
@app.route('/read', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def read():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Getting the data to update from headers of post request
        info = int(request.headers.get('info'))

        # Trying to keep the changes with a global variable
        global var_g
        var_g = info

    print(var_g)

    # Procesing data
    if var_g == 0:
        color = "No color"
    elif ( var_g > 0 and var_g < 100 ):
        color = "red"
    elif ( var_g >= 100 ):
        color = "blue"
    else:
        color = "Unknow"
    print(color)

    return jsonify(color = color)

# Index
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Html side

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> State of colors </title>
  </head>
<body>
    <p> The color state is  </p>
     <!--Conecting the results from function /read -->
    <p> <span id=results>  ---  </span> </p>

    <!--   json jquery  -  AJAX -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type=text/javascript>
        function colors() {
            $.getJSON('/read',
            // Getting the updated color
            function(data) {
                // conecting results to jsonify
                $("#results").text(data.color);
            });
            // Updating every 2 secons
            setTimeout(function() {
                        colors();
            }, 2000);
        }
        // Starting on load
        window.onload = colors;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use websockets for what you are describing

Comment: I am using [Flask socket.io](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for such tasks. Its super simple to use, even simpler than AJAX.

Comment: Really thanks charlietfl and @Roman, I am going to check more deeply about socket.io

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl said, you need to use [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to send *server to client* notifications on the state update. Unfortunately `flask` then is not the best option since it requires usually one thread per request classical approach. Each websocket connection is kind of a long running request, so after some amount of established connections using flask you may run out of threads (workers). One possible way to overcome is to switch from flask as your framework to [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). There is a nice [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library already to support both HTTP and websockets servers out of the box.

Here is a quick example how the code might look like then (did not run it though, may require some adjustments):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp.web

your_state_here = {'counter': 0}

active_clients = []

async def index(request):
    return aiohttp.web.Response(text='<your template here>')


async def do_update(request):
    # your logic here

    your_state_here['counter'] += 1

    for ws in active_clients:
        ws.send_str('updated %s' % your_state_here['counter'])

    return aiohttp.web.Response(text='Ok')


async def on_state_update(request):
    ws = aiohttp.web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)

    active_clients.append(ws)

    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            if msg.data == 'close':
                active_clients.remove(ws)
                await ws.close()

    return ws


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app = aiohttp.web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', index)
    app.router.add_route('POST', '/do_update', do_update)
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/updates', on_state_update)
    aiohttp.web.run_app(app, port=3000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @IvanVelichko, definitely I am going to look around about asyncio and WebSocket cheers.